# Adjust the positioning of PDF content

Tags: pdf, pdftk

Is there any way to adjust the positioning of PDF content? For example, suppose a PDF has the text "Hello World" written in the top left and is otherwise transparent, and I want to move this text 5 inches down and leave it in the same horizontal position. Are there any tools that can do this without converting to and from an image format (which would lose transparency I believe)?

For my purposes, the solution can not be through the use of a graphical editing application, as I need it scripted. Also, I would prefer a solution that works in most modern POSIX like enviroments, but I would settle for anything that works in Ubuntu 16.04.

Of course, such a tool may move text or other items partially or fully off the sheet. I am fine with any approach to handling that problem, because it won't happen in my situation.

pdftk tends to have a lot of solutions to PDF issues, but I can not find a solution using it. Perhaps I am missing something.

Answer (score -1):

I would highy suggest the program called Adobe Acrobat.
https://acrobat.adobe.com/dk/da/free-trial-download.html?mv=search&sdid=QLD1PHC5&s_kwcid=AL!3085!3!114913076060!b!!g!!gratis%20%2Bacrobat&ef_id=WITrQwAAACj_84e5:20170128134025:s
(not sponsored)

It's a great program for setting up PDF files to look great

Comment: Can that be used from the command line? I thought it was gui only.